# Check if just GPS is enabled on Android

Tags: java, android, android-gps

Right now, i am using a code that checks if "Location Services" is enabled but what i really need is to check if the "Use GPS satellites" option is checked because "Use wireless networks" does not work for my app.

[Image that shows GPS enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYH0g.png)

MainActivity.java

```
 final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER ) ) {

        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        HomeFragment.displayPromptForEnablingGPS(this);}
    }
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public static void displayPromptForEnablingGPS(
        final Activity activity)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    final String action = Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;
    final String message = "Não foi possível localiza-lo."
            + " Por favor habilite o GPS ou qualquer"
            + " outro serviço de localização para encontrar"
            + " as acompanhantes próximas de você.";


    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                            activity.startActivity(new Intent(action));
                            System.exit(0);
                            d.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

    builder.create().show();


}
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem?!!

Comment: The problem is that my current code does not check if the GPS option is enabled/disabled in location services

Comment: your code first checks if `NETWORK_PROVIDER` is disabled, then checks if `GPS_PROVIDER` is disabled, then displays the prompt. If all you want is the `GPS_PROVIDER` then remove that outer if - don't check (or use) the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` at all. its that simple.